# Boostrap 4 Flexbox Row is showing in columns as apposed to rows?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I have the following code and based on the examples I've found it looks as though this should be writing them out in horizontal rows but it's actually being rendered into columns?

```
<div class="d-flex">
    <div class="flex-row">
        <div class="p-2">January</div>
        <div class="p-2">February</div>
        <div class="p-2">March</div>
        <div class="p-2">April</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-row">
        <div class="p-2">May</div>
        <div class="p-2">June</div>
        <div class="p-2">July</div>
        <div class="p-2">August</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-row">
        <div class="p-2">September</div>
        <div class="p-2">October</div>
        <div class="p-2">November</div>
        <div class="p-2">December</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> "Flexbox Row is showing in columns as apposed to rows?"

Because `flex-row` is not `display:flex`. The `flex-row` should be in the same element as `d-flex`:

```
<div>
    <div class="d-flex flex-row">
            <div class="p-2">January</div>
            <div class="p-2">February</div>
            <div class="p-2">March</div>
            <div class="p-2">April</div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex flex-row">
            <div class="p-2">May</div>
            <div class="p-2">June</div>
            <div class="p-2">July</div>
            <div class="p-2">August</div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex flex-row">
            <div class="p-2">September</div>
            <div class="p-2">October</div>
            <div class="p-2">November</div>
            <div class="p-2">December</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/HnEbrelWCC